# How to save sklearn FeatureUnion?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm doing some reinforcement learning with radial basis function features, and I decided to use sklearn to generate the features, as found here:

https://github.com/dennybritz/reinforcement-learning/blob/master/PolicyGradient/Continuous%20MountainCar%20Actor%20Critic%20Solution.ipynb

Things are going great in my work using this:

```
featurizer = sklearn.pipeline.FeatureUnion([
        ("rbf1", RBFSampler(gamma=5.0, n_components=50)),
        ("rbf2", RBFSampler(gamma=2.0, n_components=50)),
        ("rbf3", RBFSampler(gamma=1.0, n_components=50)),
        ("rbf4", RBFSampler(gamma=0.5, n_components=50))
        ])

featurizer.fit(scaler.transform(observation_examples))

def featurise_state(state):
    scaled = scaler.transform([state])
    featurised = featurizer.transform(scaled)
    return featurised[0]
```

The problem is, I want to be able to save the model for analysis and using again later, but I can't seem to work out how to save and load the FeatureUnion/pipeline to be used later.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't seem to have much idea about `FeatureUnion` but you can try `pickle` module. Hope it solves the problem:)

Answer (score 0):

You could use pickle:

```
import pickle

# Save (serialize)
pickle.dump(featurizer, open( "featurizer.p", "wb" ) )

# Load
featurizer = pickle.load( open( "featurizer.p", "rb" ) )
```

With `dump` you will save your object `featurizer` in a binary file.
And you then will be able to load it again with `load`.

Comment: Thank you! This seemed to work for what I needed!

Comment: @Rivers would you do save after the featurizer.fit() step and when you load at a later time you can run the transform on the fitted featurizer?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, then yes. Simply put, pickle is used to store on disk what is in RAM (that is "serialization"). Your variable (your object), that is loaded in RAM, will be saved on your HDD/SSD as a file, and when you will load this file with pickle, you will find  this variable/object as it was at the time you saved it. Docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html